# click event on card not fired on cloned item owl-carousel 2

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel to display products in that I have products listed on cards with add to cart button in it but add to cart button on a cloned item doesn't fire the click event.

> I know there is a lot of question about this but in all cases, the answer is to make loop option false but I want loop option in my case.
>   `loop: false`
>
> Also, carousel click doesn't work for me also,
>   `$('.bstsrv-carousel').on('click', '.item', function () {
>       alert("click");
>   });`

Here is my carousel:

```
<div class="carousel-wrap">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme bstsrv-carousel">
        <div class="product card" product-id="i" product-color="#D18B49" *ngFor="let item of packages; let i = index">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="../../assets/img/carousel/main/carousel1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <h1 class="title">{{ item.name }}</h1>
            <div class="product-description stack-card-desc">
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="let desc of item.desc">
                        {{ desc }}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="product-checkout-actions daily-offer-cart">
                <button class="add-to-cart dailyoffer-add" *ngIf="!item.isInCart" name="'addtocart' + i"
                    (click)="AddToCart(item)">
                    Add to Cart
                </button>
                <button class="add-to-cart dailyoffer-add" *ngIf="item.isInCart" name="'removecart' + i"
                    (click)="removeCart(item)">
                    Remove
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my carousel option:

```
  $(".bstsrv-carousel").owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    loop:  true,
    stagePadding: 0,
    margin: 0,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 4000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    nav: true,
    dots: false,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 3,
        nav: true
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: use `https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples` angular library for that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using jQuery to set-up the owl-carousel. You should use the library that is made specifically for Angular: https://github.com/vitalii-andriiovskyi/ngx-owl-carousel-o

Angular has a very specific way of initialising its template code, which will not be triggered if you use the jQuery component. So basically when the jQuery component clones one of its carousel items, the Angular code will not function. Migrating to the angular jQuery carousel library should be the way to go.

Comment: my mistake I just copied but i changed in my code while using and didn't work

Comment: Ans there is a reason I went for jquery this just half of my code there is a lot in carousel I am handling and that cannot done by angular way

Comment: Angular has a very specific way of initialising its template code, which will not be triggered if you use the jQuery component. So basically when the jQuery component clones one of its carousel items, the Angular code will not function. Migrating to the angular jQuery carousel library should be the way to go.

Updated answer with this